# HTML check box with JS

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
```

How do I get JavaScript to recognize if the box is checked or unchecked without altering the the above HTML code.

Comment: `Element.checked`

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448988/jquery-select-checkbox-based-on-name-and-value

Answer (score 0):

Use querySelector and get the element by name

```
let val = document.querySelector('[name="smoker"]').checked;
console.log(val);
```

Comment: @mason-white was this to any help?